# scikit-mobility installed but doesn't work

Tags: python

I 'm trying to work with scikit-mobility and Geolife data set. files are exactly the same with sample files the there are in its guidlines(https://scikit-mobility.github.io/scikit-mobility/index.html).but print(tdf.head()) has some errors.

```
>>>import skmob
>>> tdf = skmob.TrajDataFrame.from_file('D:\\test.csv') 
>>> print(tdf.head())
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "C:\Users\admin\.conda\envs\skmob\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5804, in head
  return self.iloc[:n]
File "C:\Users\admin\.conda\envs\skmob\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1153, in      __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Users\admin\.conda\envs\skmob\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1691, in    _getitem_axis
   return self._get_slice_axis(key, axis=axis)
 File "C:\Users\admin\.conda\envs\skmob\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1727, in   _get_slice_axis
  return self.obj._slice(slice_obj, axis=axis)
 File "C:\Users\admin\.conda\envs\skmob\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4305, in _slice
  result = self._constructor_from_mgr(new_mgr, axes=new_mgr.axes)
 File "C:\Users\admin\.conda\envs\skmob\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 649, in   _constructor_from_mgr
  return self._constructor(df, copy=False)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'copy'
```

please help.